# How do I enable Bitbucket Branching Model inheritance via the API?

Tags: bitbucket-api

In the bitbucket interface, there is a toggle that you can click to inherit branching strategies at the top level for a project from the repository's project group settings. I have over 100 of these I need to go through. Is there a call to the REST API that I can make that would set it?

[image: the toggle.]

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a same solution, but it appears the API doesn't cover this functionality (yet).

I've played around with all manor of API calls/parameters in an attempt to discover the right variable.  Even inspecting the payload from the web UI but sadly no luck.  I think we're just gonna have to wait.. that or loop through each repo and apply the same configuration.

> There is **currently a side effect when using this API endpoint**. If the repository is inheriting branching model settings from its project, updating the branching model for this repository will **disable the project setting inheritance**.
> We have deprecated this side effect and will remove it on **1 August 2022**.

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-branching-model/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-branching-model-settings-put